# scss for statement nth-child animation

Tags: css, animation, sass

I want to use a for statement in SCSS to make the animations appear sequentially in the p tag. I want an animation effect that zooms in and then returns to its original size. I want a 0.5 second time difference between the effects. I'm not sure how to use the for statement in SCSS. I searched in several places and wrote the code below, but it only prints the p-tag on the screen and doesn't animate the p-tag. I would be grateful if you could share your knowledge.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb3AF.png)

HTML

```
<body>
    <header>
        <p>my name</p>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <section>
            <div class="scP">
                <p>Welcome to my Webpage</p>
                <p>I'm a student</p>
                <p>Thank you</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

SCSS

```
section{
    /* border: 1px solid red; */
    padding-top: 200px;
    .scP{
        p{
            text-align: center;
            padding: 30px 0px;
            @for $i from 1 through 3 {
                &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
                    animation-name: expand;
                    animation-timing-function: linear;
                    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                    animation-delay: $i+(-0.7s);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
@keyframes expand{
    50%{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

```css
section {
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
  padding-top: 200px;
}

section .scP p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 0px;
}

section .scP p:nth-child(1) {
  animation-name: expand;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

section .scP p:nth-child(2) {
  animation-name: expand;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 1.3s;
}

section .scP p:nth-child(3) {
  animation-name: expand;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 2.3s;
}

@keyframes expand {
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <p>my name</p>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <section>
      <div class="scP">
        <p>Welcome to my Webpage</p>
        <p>I'm a student</p>
        <p>Thank you</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good, but you are missing the `animation-duration` property. Without it, the animation goes from 0% to 100% instantly and you don't see it happening.

Comment: Thanks to you, I found the problem. Have a nice day!!

Comment: @KIMEUNSEO If Juan solved your problem, be sure and hit the checkmark next to his answer saying it was solved and giving him credit